# Map List<Class> to List<Class> with automapper for .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

I have two models. The first is:

```
public class Push
{
    public int PushId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string PackageId { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Advertiser { get; set; }
    public PushTemplate PushTemplate { get; set; }
    public string TemplateType { get; set; }
    public string IntervalType { get; set; }
    public int TopDateTimeBorder{ get; set; }
    public int  BottomDateTimeBorder { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClientStartDateTime { get; set; }
    public string LangCode { get; set; }
    public string PushTitle { get; set; }
    public string PushBody { get; set; }
    public string FCMResponse { get; set; }
    public bool Sent { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public Distribution Distribution { get; set; }
    public Push()
    {
        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

and the second is:

```
public class FailedPush
{
    public int FailedPushId { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string PackageId { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Advertiser { get; set; }
    public PushTemplate PushTemplate { get; set; }
    public string TemplateType { get; set; }
    public string IntervalType { get; set; }
    public int TopDateTimeBorder{ get; set; }
    public int  BottomDateTimeBorder { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClientStartDateTime { get; set; }
    public string LangCode { get; set; }
    public string PushTitle { get; set; }
    public string PushBody { get; set; }
    public string FCMResponse { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public Distribution Distribution { get; set; }
    public FailedPush()
    {
        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

I would like to get a list of `FailedPush` models from a list of `Push` models if the property `Sent` is false.

So I have the following code for this:

```
 var failedPushes = _mapper.Map<List<Push>, List<FailedPush>>(await pushes.Where(x => !x.Sent).ToListAsync());
```

But `failedPushes` is empty. To inject mapper I user `IMapper` interface:

```
// class prop 
private readonly IMapper _mapper;

... 

// constructor 

public ScopedProcessingService(IMapper mapper) 
{ 
...
_mapper = mapper;
...
}
```

And in the `Startup.cs` class I have the following:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

So what is wrong?

Comment: the id in both your classes have different property names. "PushId" and "FailedPushId". Either you need the same name or map it explicitly in the mapper.

Comment: Why not just use the same class for both, and have a status property? :D

Comment: @andreasnico no no ) I need one more)

Comment: @AzharKhorasany how to say for automapper that I want set `FailedPushId` to 0?

Comment: Have you configured the `CreateMap<Push, FailedPush>()` correctly?

Comment: @AndréSanson no I dont. Where I have to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a configuration of your mapping classes.

Automapper will automatically search for classes that inherit Profile to create the configuration.

Create a folder Profile and put your configurations there.

```
public class PushProfile : Profile
{
    public PushProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Push, FailedPush>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I already had `Profile`. But my mistake is my `Profile` had this call: `CreateMap<List<Push>, List<FailedPush>>();` And it did not work. Your way works!